# Java String.split() splitting every character instead of given regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that I want to split into an array:

`SEQUENCE： 1A→2B→3C`

I tried the following regular expression:

`((.*\s)|([\x{2192}]*))`

```
1. \x{2192} is the arrow mark
2. There is a space after the colon, I used that as a reference for matching the first part
```

and it works in testers(Patterns in OSX)
[image]

but it splits the string into this:

`[, , 1, A, , 2, B, , 3, C]`

How can I achieve the following?:

`[1A,2B,3C]`

This is the test code:

```
String str = "SEQUENCE： 1A→2B→3C"; //Note that there's an extra space after the colon
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("(.*\\s)|([\\x{2192}]*)")));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in Richard Sitze's post, the main problem with the regex is that it should use `+` rather than `*`. Additionally, there are further improvements you can make to your regex:

- Instead of `\\x{2192}`, use `\u2192`. And because it's a single character, you don't need to put it into a character class (`[...]`), you can just use `\u2192+` directly.
- Also, because `|` binds more loosely than `.*\\s` and `\u2192+`, you won't need the parentheses there either. So your final expression is simply `".*\\s|\u2192+"`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation, It works but how do I get rid of the leading "match"? The array looks like this: `[, 1A, 2B, 3C]` , I don't want the first empty element.

Comment: Chop off the `SEQUENCE: ` first, before doing the splitting: `str.replaceFirst("SEQUENCE: ", "").split("\u2192+")`

Answer (score 5):

The `\u2192*` will match 0 or more arrows - which is why you're splitting on every character (splitting on empty string).  Try changing `*` to `+`.